# Is there any way to make appear only the initial of the last names of the authors followed by the year?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I need to compress the references as much as possible. Supposing to have:

```
J. Chen and X. Ran. “Deep Learning With Edge Computing: A Review.”
In: Proc. IEEE 107.8 (2019), pp. 1655–1674.
```

I want to obtain

```
CR2019 “Deep Learning With Edge Computing: A Review.”
In: Proc. IEEE 107.8 (2019), pp. 1655–1674.
```

Is there any way to make this using biblatex?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** removed `xstring` package according to moewe's comment

This produces your desired format:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{chen2019,
    author={J. Chen and X. Ran},
    title={Deep Learning With Edge Computing: A Review.},
    journal={Proc. IEEE},
    volume={107},
    number={8},
    year={2019},
    pages={1655--1674}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
    \def\bibinitperiod{}%
    \namepartfamilyi%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\value{liststop}}%
    {\thefield{year}}{}% append year after last author
}
% only a space between author and title, no comma or period
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\space}

\begin{document}

\cite{chen2019}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can avoid `xstring` if you use `\namepartfamilyi` (never thought it would come in handy) and locally make `\bibinitperiod` empty.

Comment: @moewe Good point, thank you. I updated the answer. I though about using `\namepartfamilyi` before together with the `terseinits` option, but redefining `\bibinitperiod` locally is better.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what the wider context (citation style and application) of this is, but you may as well go for an `alphabetic` style and suppress the names in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\renewbibmacro{author}{}
\renewbibmacro{editor}{}
\renewbibmacro{editor+others}{}
\renewbibmacro{translator}{}
\renewbibmacro{translator+others}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [SR98] “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

If you need to base this on a `numeric` style, you could still try to make use of the alphabetic label.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric, labelalpha]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\renewbibmacro{author}{\printfield{labelalpha}}
\renewbibmacro{editor}{\printfield{labelalpha}}
\renewbibmacro{editor+others}{\printfield{labelalpha}}
\renewbibmacro{translator}{\printfield{labelalpha}}
\renewbibmacro{translator+others}{\printfield{labelalpha}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [4] SR98 “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: As can be seen in the example: The names might not be the biggest issue for a compact bibliography. Article and journal titles can take up quite a bit of space as well.